# az-cli not returning resources however they can be viewed through portal

Tags: azure

I am trying to fetch a list of all `Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/`.

```
az resource list --resource-type "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/" --subscription "operations"
```

The servicebus exists in the respective subscription and can be viewed by my same account through portal.

I am already into respective subscription and have also tried specifying it explicitly, but it only returns and empty list `[]`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command to list the ServiceBus Namespace uses `az resource` instead of `az servicebus`

Use the following command to list your Azure ServiceBus Namespaces `az servicebus namespace list [--resource-group]`

Reference to Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-namespace-list

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can list namespaces across `all` subscriptions at once, we have multiple subscriptions and doing it one by one would be troublesome.

Comment: U might have to write a cli or powershell script to achieve that IMO